# Verificar se o dia anterior é feriado e/ou domingo

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou tendo problemas para desenvolver uma lógica de validação de datas.
A variável `dataFecha` é chamada com -1 dia para já validar o dia anterior.

Porém quando eu vou testar as validações, ele não subtraí (-1) dia na variável, para validar o sábado e/ou antes ao feriado.

## Validações

1. Validar se o dia anterior não é domingo. Caso for, pegar o caixa de
   sábado.
2. Validar se o dia anterior não é feriado. Caso for, pegar do dia
   antes do feriado. ¹Caso o dia anterior ao feriado for domingo, pegar
   o caixa de sábado.

## Código.

```
  //Verificar se houve fechamento para caixa no dia anterior e/ou se esta aberto.
  FechamentoCaixa objFec = new FechamentoCaixa();
  Feriados_Nacionais objFeriado = new Feriados_Nacionais();
  //Instancia a varíavel com -1 dia para validar o dia anterior
  dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

  ////Verifica se o dia anterior é domingo. Caso for, irá verificar o caixa de sabado.
  if (Convert.ToDateTime(dataFecha).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
   dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  }
  //Verifica se o dia anterior é feriado. Caso for, irá verificar o dia antes de ontem
  if (objFeriado.ConsultarFeriado(dataFecha) > 0) {
   dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   //Verifica se o dia anterior ao feriado é domingo. Caso for, irá verificar o de sabado.
   if (Convert.ToDateTime(dataFecha).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
    dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   }
  }
```

Comment: acho que bastaria você pegar o maior caixa antes da data atual. Se por ventura a empresa não funcionar no meio da semana, ou funcionar em um feriado ou domingo, como ficaria ?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não está pegando a data de fechamento para subtrair 1 dia. Tem que ser cumulativo. Note que eu simplifiquei bastante o código.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dataFechamento = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        dataFechamento = isSunday(dataFechamento);
        if (new Feriados_Nacionais().ConsultarFeriado(dataFecha) > 0) {
            dataFechamento = dataFechamento.AddDays(-1);
            dataFechamento = isSunday(dataFechamento);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(dataFechamento);
        DateTime isSunday(DateTime date) => date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? date.AddDays(-1) : date;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/prh0du). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3TNhhR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/SundayANdHolyday.cs).

Para facilitar o teste e não ter criar o objeto de feriado eu mudei para `true` nos IDEs *online*, e usei uma data fixa, mas aqui está da forma como deve ser seu código.

Eu acho que tem outros problemas neste código, inclusive de conceito. Principalmente no `Feriados_Nacionais`.

Comment: bigown, o método `ConsultarFeriado` não ficaria legal como um método de extensão?

Comment: @Marconi não sei, quase sempre isto é abusado, se for muito bem pensado, talvez, mas não parece ser o caso. Na verdade seria mais um método estático, e até esta versão C# não permite método estático de extensão, pode ser que tenha na 8.

Comment: Eu ia fazer uma coisa e fiz outra, a função local precisa ter outro nome, e dá pra simplificar mais, depois eu arrumo :)

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente procurei usar somente o tipo *DateTime* no seu algoritmo.
Outro detalhe, o *DateTime.Now* retorna o dia atual, logo se for segunda, o dia anterior é domingo, para pegar o sábado, você tem que diminuir dois do *DateTime.Now*.

```
//Verificar se houve fechamento para caixa no dia anterior e/ou se esta aberto.
  FechamentoCaixa objFec = new FechamentoCaixa();
  Feriados_Nacionais objFeriado = new Feriados_Nacionais();
  //Instancia a varíavel com -1 dia para validar o dia anterior
  DateTime dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

  ////Verifica se o dia anterior é domingo. Caso for, irá verificar o caixa de sabado.
  if (dataFecha.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
   dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2); //retorna sábado
  }
  //Verifica se o dia anterior é feriado. Caso for, irá verificar o dia antes de ontem
  if (objFeriado.ConsultarFeriado(dataFecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) > 0) {
   dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
   //Verifica se o dia anterior ao feriado é domingo. Caso for, irá verificar o de sabado.
   if (dataFecha.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
    dataFecha = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2); //retorna sábado
   }
  }
```